# How to bind model to formbuilder using reactive forms in angular8

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, reactive

i have used reactive forms in my application and binding to html using formcontrolName. But now instead of declaring the properties inside the formbuilder, i need to call a model and assign that model to the formbuilder and use it in html.
I been through many links but didnt find anywhere how to work based on my requirement.

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade h-100 active show" id="tab-user_1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="user_1"
    *ngIf="userInfoForm" [formGroup]="userInfoForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Agent Code <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="agentCode" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
 this.userInfoForm = this.FB.group({
        Id: 0,
        agentCode: this.agentCode,
        userName: [''],
        firstName: [''],
        middleName: '',
        lastName: [''],
        department: [''],
      });
      this.userInfoForm.controls['agentCode'].disable();
```

model.ts:

```
export class UserFormDetails {
   Id: number;
   agentCode: number;
   userName: string;
   firstName: string;
   middleName: string;
   lastName: string;
   department: string;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-esempy?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.ts)

Answer (score 4):

based on the comments, it sounds like you want a dynamic form based on a model... there is no "out of the box" solution to do this. You can write your own form model:

```
interface MyFormModelField {
  initial?: {
    value: any,
    disabled: boolean
  },
  controlOptions?: AbstractControlOptions
  // anything you find useful really?
}

export type MyFormModel<T> = Record<keyof T, MyFormModelField>
```

then implement it like so:

```
const USER_FORM_MODEL: MyFormModel<UserFormDetails> = {
    Id: { },
    agentCode: {
        initial: {
          value: '',
          disabled: true
        },
        controlOptions: {
          validators: Validators.required
        }
    },
    userName: { },
    firstName: { },
    middleName: { },
    lastName: { },
    department: { },
}
```

then you could write a service for producing form groups based on an instance of the form model...

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyFormBuilder {
  constructor(private: fb) { }

  buildForm<T>(formModel: MyFormModel<T>) {
    const fg = Object.keys(formModel).reduce((grp, k) => {
      const fld = formModel[k];
      return Object.assign(grp, {
        [k]: [fld.initial || '', fld.controlOptions]
      })
    }, {});
    return this.fb.group(fg);
  }
}
```

now, anytime you make changes to the `UserFormDetails` interface, typescript will yell at you to update the corresponding form model with the field information... and while updates won't flow "automatically" from a model update, you at least have some type safety in your forms. I'd personally stop here.

This next part isn't perfect, and I'm not a fan of it, but if you really want the next step to have it be more or less automatic from the class definition, you could write a function to build a default form model from a class, like this:

```
function buildDefaultFormModel<T>(model: new () => T) {
  return Object.keys(new model()).reduce((form, k) => {
      return Object.assign(form, {[k]: {}})
  }, {} as MyFormModel<T>)
}
```

this requires 2 things, 1, the class your building a form for MUST have a default specified for each field, fields without defaults wont't be included. (This introduces a hidden dependency on fields having default values, which is why I don't like this method, however, you CAN configure ts to yell at you if you write a class that has properties without defaults or constructor assignments):

```
class UserFormDetails {
   Id: number = 0;
   agentCode: number = 0;
   userName: string = '';
   firstName: string = '';
   middleName: string = '';
   lastName: string = '';
   department: string = '';
}
```

2, the object constructor must take no parameters. but TS will yell at you if you try to misuse it in this case.

the function could be used like this:

```
const USER_FORM_MODEL: MyFormModel<UserFormDetails> = {
  ...buildDefaultFormModel(UserFormDetails),
  ...{
    agentCode: {
      initial: {
        value: '',
        disabled: true
      },
      controlOptions: {
        validators: Validators.required
      }
    },
  }
}
```

this way you can use default fields, and also provide an override for specific fields.

finally, you could also leverage this form model to build a template, but that's a bigger task.

here's a blitz with this all implemented (and I went ahead and cleaned up the controller code): https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-qtnasc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.validators.ts

Comment: Thanks for response, it helps me. If i am unclear in any concept i will get back to you. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You have to use patchValue to bind you model in the FormGroup form control.

```
this.userInfoForm = this.FB.group({
        Id: 0,
        agentCode: this.agentCode,
        userName: [''],
        firstName: [''],
        middleName: '',
        lastName: [''],
        department: [''],
      });
```

this is correct.
When you get UserFormDetails object you have to pass it to form you have to do :

```
 this.userInfoForm.patchValue({
   'Id': UserFormDetails.id 
    ...
})
```

and when you had to pass the form controls value to object:

```
 this.UserFormDetail.id = this.userInfoForm.get('Id').value
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks for response,but i am not looking for this, i want to bind model to formGroup

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking..? What do you mean with ‘bind model’..?

Comment: I believe he wants do the same thing I wrote but without patchValue, directly using model.

Comment: Hi, here i need to assign the model values to formbuilder, so if there are any extra fields added in future, i can just add it in model and so will be updated in the formBuilder

Comment: Never came across such a case. Also, according to your requirement, if an extra property is added to the model and in the formBuilder, you might also need to show it on the UI in form of an input field or so. Hidden elements can be a case but then also the values won't be updated using the form so can be done directly from the logic in the .ts file.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the solution you are looking for:

```
private initUserForm() {
   // mapping the object into the form model
   this.userInfoForm = this.FB.group({ ...this.userDetails });

   // if you want to add validators or disable buttons...
   this.userInfoForm.controls.agentCode.setValidators(Validators.required); // adding validations
   this.userInfoForm.controls.agentCode.disable();
   // console.log(this.userInfoForm.controls);
}
```

This way covers your need of "binding" which is not a real binding as the framework doesn't allow such thing, but it allows you to map from the object model/values to create the reactive form model.

See how after adding an extraField, the forms pick up that control and its value:

[image]

Comment: how does this work exactly?  The docs for using FormBuilder (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#using-the-formbuilder-service-to-generate-controls that's what your this.FB is, right?) expect an array for each value in the object parameter to this.FB.group(), with the initial field value as the first value in the array, and sync and async validators as 2nd and 3rd elements.  In that case, I'm surprised the .group() method accepts an object with non-array fields.  And I would think this blows up as soon as one of your fields on the this.userDetails model is an array.